# Evaluate a triple integral over a box

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question has two parts:
(a) What is the region $E$ over which $\iiint_{E} 2 - |x| -|y| -|z|\;dV$ is maximum? (b) For this region $E$, what is the value of the integral?

I think I got (a): For this triple integral to be maximum, we want the integrand to be non-negative, so $|x|+|y|+|z|\leq 2$, which describes a box. For (b), the bounds seem to be $-2\leq x \leq 2, -2\leq y\leq 2, -2\leq z\leq 2$. To evaluate this triple integral, I think I have to get rid of the absolute value sign somehow. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x|+|y|+|z| < 2$ describes an octahedron, and not a cube.  You can exploit symmetry.  Integrate over the tetrahedron in the first octant bound by $x+y+z = 2$  and multiply by 8.

$8\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x}\int_0^{2-x-y} 2 -(x+y+z) \ dz \  dy\ dx$